# Appending weeks to rolling date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, week-number

I have a daily rolling date column, [table].[Date], from 2020-06-27 to today.

I need to append a week number, with 2020-06-27 to 2020-07-03 as week 1 and so forth. Saturday to Friday defined as the week.

I have tried the following. Though this only defines the *week of the year*, so I would end up with overlaps when a year passes. Also, it does not define the first date as week 1.

```
datepart(week,[table].[Date]) as Week
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you are using SQL Server (based on the SSMS tag).

You can count the days and divide by 7:

```
select ceiling(datediff(day, '2020-06-26', t.date) / 7.0) as week_number
```

Or:

select 1 + floor(datediff(day, '2020-06-27', t.date) / 7.0) as week_number

If you don't want to hardcode the first date, you can use a window function:

```
select ceiling(datediff(day, min(t.date) over (), t.date) / 7.0) as week_number
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but the first date (2020-06-27) has week_number as 0 and the second date (2020-06-28) with week_number as 1. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Fixed this using the hardcode option and using '2020-06-26' as the first date. Thanks again!